# Eclipse jumping to function name on Ctrl-S

Tags: java, eclipse

When I press Ctrl-S to save my Java file in Eclipse it's jumping to the function name. This is very annoying. Someone know what to do about this?

Comment: What OS and version of Eclipse are you using?

Comment: I have exactly the same and none of the solutions below help. (It jumps to function "setup" and highlight all words "setup" (as if a search was done for setup).

Answer (score 3):

Go to Window->Preferences->General->Keys (you can also search for `Keys` in the main Preferences window). You most likely have added a binding which makes eclipse jump to the function name when you press `ctrl`+`s`.

Another place to look is Window->Preferences->Java->Code Style->Clean Up and Window->Preferences->Java->Editor->Save Actions. That is where all actions are defined which happen when you save/clean up a document.

Answer (score 1):

Try looking at your keyboard bindings. I certainly don't have this problem on either of my Eclipse installs. You might have <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd> assigned to two different actions?

Answer (score 1):

This was really annoying problem for me also.

Solved it by going to Preferences->General->Workspace and unchecking "Refresh on access" checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with `Ctrl+C` malfunctioning in Eclipse.

Here is a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1189002/eclipse-3-5-copy-paste-problem) regarding it.

Maybe try upgrading to the latest version if the above solutions do not work.